# JPA persist with OneToMany ManyToOne

Tags: jpa

I am trying to persist entities with @OneToMany and @ManyToOne relationships.

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy="customer", cascade=CascadeType.ALL, fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
private Collection<Address> addresses = new LinkedHashSet<Address>();

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="customer_id", referencedColumnName="customer_id")
private Customer customer;
```

problem is that it inserts NULL instead of customer_id in the `address` table.

could you suggest why is that happening.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please show the complete mappings (without constructors and methods) plus the code you use to persist. -> edit question

Comment: a little code will actually performs the transaction will be helpful!

Comment: It's just a blind shooting here if you don't show us the code for the actual persistence operation.

Answer (score 4):

That probably means that you didn't initialize the `customer` field of the addresses. If that isn't the solution, then show us your code.

Comment: public void createCustomer(Customer customer) {
  em.persist(customer);
  em.flush();
 }
this is actual code that creates customers and here i add address 
in address collection

ApplicationContext applicationContext = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("META-INF/spring/app-context.xml");
  Customer c = new Customer();
  c.setName("Bruce Eckel");
  Address a = new Address();
  c.getAddresses().add(a);
  a.setAddress("submarine str. # 45");
  // retrieve service bean
  CustomerService service = applicationContext.getBean("customerService", CustomerService.class);
  service.createCustomer(c);

Comment: oh year thanks. i know there was something simple and could realize what :) thanks a lot!